# CanI see and copy the templates from Wikipedia or other Wikis?

Tags: templates, wiki

I am a postgraduate student in experimental physics, and my university offers a wiki service as a lab book for different groups. 
 Unfortunately they only offer the basic functionalities, like links and categories, and they have not implemented the full plethora of templates of Wikipedia. 
 All the information about this Wiki is [here](https://help.uis.cam.ac.uk/email-telephony-and-collaboration/map-collaborative-services/managed-wiki-service), and when I contacted them directly they confirmed that:

> We only install  a limited set of extensions to the Managed Wiki 
>   Service, due to the maintenance and security difficulties that can be created
>   when doing upgrades.

-

So, I am wondering: can I not just copy some of the template definitions that are used on Wikipedia?

For example our Managed Wiki has the templates `{{CURRENTYEAR}}`, `{{CURRENTMONTH}}` and `{{CURRENTDAY}}`, but **not** `{{DATE}}` or `{{DAY-1}}` (for yesterday's date). 
 Since we are using this as a lab book, we have a page for each day. We can link to today's page with the first three templates, but not to yesterday's page because of the lack of `{{DAY-1}}` - we have to type yesterday's date by hand.

But surely Wikipedia must have these templates defined somewhere? Can I not copy and paste that definition and make my own templates in our Managed Wiki?

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste some of the template definitions into your app?

Comment: Where do I find the template definition on Wikipedia? I never seem to be able to go deeper than the template documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution:

On any template page on Wikipedia (e.g. = [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:DATE)), one needs to go to the top right  **View source** , and copy that code into the Managed Wiki.

So it is not **Edit page** as suggested by other answers, as this only provides code understandable within Wikipedia. 
 For **View source**, however, copy and paste works fine on other MediaWiki-based systems.

My ManagedWiki then just has to enable extensions (like `ParserFunctions`) is order to understand code like `#if` or `#switch`.

Answer (score 0):

To view template definitions in Wikipedia, you need to sign up for an account. You can then go to any page and "edit" that page. When editing you will be able to view all template meta.

In the top right corner of Wikipedia, there is a link that says "Create account".

Once you have created an account you will see a link towards the top that says "Edit Page".

After you have clicked on "Edit Page" you will need to click on the pencil towards the top right corner and click "Edit Source". You will then be able to see all meta in it's source view.

Wikipedia uses a "template system". For example, the "Info Box" on the right side of most pages commonly uses this template:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox

A few other templates:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:CURRENTYEARYY
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Date

I have assumed your using MediaWiki to implement your Wiki. Here is their documentation https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Contents

Documentation for copying from one MediaWiki to another: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Copying_from_one_wiki_to_another

Comment: Where can I see the definition of <code>CURRENTYEAR</code>?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Can you give me an example of where CURRENTYEAR is used on Wikipedia?

Comment: Not so far: I can go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Currentdate and see the instructions on how to use the syntax. I want to see the code behind it, the one used to define it. So that I can copy that in my Managed Wiki, so that I can use it on mine too.

Comment: {{CURRENTYEARYY}}

Comment: How does it work out the year?? Where is the code behind CURRENYEARYY?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163543/discussion-between-mike-stratton-and-superciocia).

Comment: It's fine I think I found the answer, here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Copying_from_one_wiki_to_another